# How to rotate (any degree) ImageData object and receive new "rotated" ImagaData.data array

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have an imageData object containing elevation data encoded in rgba. I need to compute the elevation profile at specified heading. For one pixel width line and North up heading it is easy as it is just a column of the imagaData array. For specified degree it is also easy as it involves simple trigonometry to compute x,y position in the array, however my requirement is more complex. In fact I need to compute elevation profile (max values) for a stripe with width larger than 1 pixel, so I need to rotate the whole image data.

In short, I need to:

1) crop image to work on smaller data ( for example centered half of the original image) - performance is important

2) rotate by center the cropped image for the specified degree, so I will have required elevation data in top up orientation in the table.

3) Scan elevation profile data, raw by ray and compute max elevation value per each row.

As this operation must be computed several times per second, I need optimized solution. I tried with transformation/rotation of canvas context, however the imageData object is not changed, so I guess I would need to save the context image (rotated) to another image object, but I am not sure how.

any hint more than welcomed

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow.
Before asking for something you should post what you have first tryed to do to solve your problem.
You can learn how to ask for something on stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Only asking for code will result in people downvoting your question and you will show minor effort in trying to solve your problem :)

Comment: The ImageData returned by ctx.getImageData is completely detached from the context, changing the drawing there won't update your ImageData, you need to call this method **after** you performed your drawings. Now, how come you even need to read it from an ImageData? Can't you hook to whatever has generated the graphics in the first place?

Comment: Thx Kaiido for the comment. Yes, that's what I have figured out, that imageData is detached from the context. I have no drawing. I want modified ImageData after the rotation (save it to another image ? or something else) to read bytes from the array.

Comment: ... Could you explain why you need to analyze this ImageData? Where are you getting these ImageDatas from? Isn't there a way your source gives you a more edible form? If I understand correctly, the bitmap contained in the ImageData is a kind of histogram is that right? If so, surely they have the data to make these histograms. Would be better to simply grab it at this stage rather than from the computed graphical visualization.

Comment: Images comes from maptiler server

https://www.maptiler.com/blog/2019/03/rgb-encoded-elevation-data-in-maptiler-cloud.html

and I am using OpenLayers ol.source.Raster to read the data for specified geo location. The data is returned as imageData

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do the math myself, as I only need to rotate part of the image. This function rotates clockwise single point (p) around (r) by angle (in radians)

```
function rotate(p, r, angle) // angle in radians, clockwise
{
var new_p = new Object();

// shortened calculation
new_p.x = Math.round(r.x + ((p.x - r.x)*Math.cos(angle) - (p.y - r.y)*Math.sin(angle)));
new_p.y = Math.round(r.y + ((p.x - r.x)*Math.sin(angle) + (p.y - r.y)*Math.cos(angle)));

return new_p;
}
```

test, rotate (0,0) by 90 deg

```
var test_p = rotate({ x:0, y:0 },{x:400,y:400},Math.PI/2)
```

result

```
{x: 800, y: 0}
```